# Why isn't "/*" invalidation sufficient to clear React build in s3 bucket from cloudfront?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm submitting my react built to an s3 bucket, and have to invalidate the old build in cloudfront. I've tried a few invalidation patterns, but haven't dug into it too much. I find I have to invalidate the /static/js/main.xyz.js and then /*, to clear the cache. Why doesn't /* work alone? This is a small build, so I'm not too concerned about creating too many invalidations.

Comment: Based on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#invalidation-specifying-objects-paths `/*` should invalidate all files in the distribution so having to invalidate the file explicitly should not be necessary.

Comment: I agree, but didn't know if maybe I was missing something. My thoughts were, maybe "all invalidate" doesn't work if you're on free tier, or it has some nesting issues. I will try just /* next time. 

I'm satisfied with the docs answer, if you want to post it as an answer I'll call it answered to close the question out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the official [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#invalidation-specifying-objects-paths) the **/*** invalidation seems to be a special case of invalidation that invalidates the entire distribution

Some more examples of invalidations are:

- **/xyz/*** invalidates the contents of xyz (but not subdirectories)
- **/xyz*** invalidates the contents of xyz and all subdirectories including their contents

etc